# How do I get input at the same time while constantly increasing a value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input

I'm pretty new to Python. I'm trying to make a text-based strategy-like game in python and I want to have a value to increase constantly(I wanna have some other values to increase or decrease at the same time too but this is just for beginning). But if I use a `While True` loop I can't do anything else in the program. It just keeps rising the value but I can't do anything else. I want it to increase continuously while I can get some inputs from the user or run some other functions. Tell me if there is a module I can use or anything else please.

```
import time
print("PLANET EARTH" + "" + "\n    Buildings:",
      "                   ", "Resources:")
class ironMine():
    def __init__(self, bc, ps, w):
        self.buildingCost = bc
        self.productionSpeed = ps
        self.warehouse = w

    def production(self):

        while True:
            print("                                      " +
                  "iron:", self.warehouse,
                   end="\r")
            self.warehouse += self.productionSpeed
            time.sleep(0.5)
            x=input("Write something")
            if x == upgrade:
                self.productionSpeed += 5
            else:
                print("there is no such command")

t1 = ironMine([300,200,100], 10, 0)
t1.production()
```

For example this part is the resource production part for iron. I just add an random input to show I cant get it done. And I don't know if this part `if x == upgrade: self.productionSpeed += 5` will update the existing `self.productionSpeed` value for object `t1`.

Comment: And, since I'm an amateur if you can help me optimize or  improve the code that would be great too.

Comment: You need to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) in order to process user inpute and at the same time do some other things simultaneously.

Comment: You don't need to have a timer running while waiting for user input. Take the time before the input starts and the time after it returns. Calculate the difference and add that to the accumulated time.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, you are trying to implement your own version of a clock, which counts up at some rate, using a loop like this:

```py
value = initial_value
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    value += rate
```

There is more to your code than that, of course; you also want to read user input and control the rate based on that. But at the core of it, you're trying to create a clock, and it's not working because your clock stops "ticking" while `input` is waiting for the user to enter something.

Instead of writing a clock, you should use one from the standard library. The [`time.monotonic()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) function works like a clock, in the sense that if you call the function twice, the difference between the two numbers is the number of seconds which elapsed between the two function calls.

The simple "clock" above, which has a variable `value` increasing at a fixed `rate`, can be replaced by a function call which calculates the current value based on the number of seconds that have elapsed, instead of continuously maintaining its current value in a variable:

```py
import time

initial_time = time.monotonic()
def get_current_value():
    current_time = time.monotonic()
    seconds = current_time - initial_time
    # use int(seconds) for discrete updates once per second
    return initial_value + rate * int(seconds)
```

For your case, where the rate can change dynamically, it is a bit more complicated, but the key idea is the same; don't write your own clock, use an existing one. Since there are two things we need to be able to do - get the current value, and change the rate - let's encapsulate those two operations in a class:

```py
import time

class TimeBasedVariable:
    def __init__(self, initial_value, rate):
        self.initial_value = initial_value
        self.rate = rate
        self.initial_time = time.monotonic()

    def get_value(self, current_time=None):
        if current_time is None:
            current_time = time.monotonic()
        seconds = current_time - self.initial_time
        return self.initial_value + self.rate * int(seconds)

    def set_rate(self, rate):
        # reset the reference point to the current time
        t = time.monotonic()
        self.initial_value = self.get_value(t)
        self.initial_time = t

        self.rate = rate
```

Note that I simplified the problem slightly by making the variable update every second, rather than every 0.5 seconds. If you do want it to update every half-second, just write `int(2 * seconds)` instead of `int(seconds)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I still can't get it print the value constantly. When the input line is on it stops printing the value. And, for your second part of the code it doesn't work for me when I try to print the value. It says: ``` Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/Atmaca/Desktop/deneme1.py", line 26, in <module> t1.get_value() File "C:/Users/Atmaca/Desktop/deneme1.py", line 13, in get_value print("iron:", self.initial_value + self.rate * int(seconds), end="\r") TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int' ```